# Treeview 選択値の保存方式を教えてください。

Tags: c#, asp.net

c# asp.netのコンポーネントTreeviewにチェックボックスを表示させて、チェックボックス選択状態をデータベース、またはファイル（XMLなど）保存して、再びその保存データを読み出したら、選択状態を再現する方法を検討中です。

Treeviewの作成は親子関係を持つマスタテーブルを作成すればできるかと考えています。

選択状態を再現する場合はどのようなテーブルまたはファイルを設計するのが良いでしょうか？

データベースはSQL server2016です。
データベースへのアクセスは.NET framework標準のSqlConnectionで実施します。

Comment: 最低でもデータベースの種類、DBへのアクセス方法の指定が必要と思います。加えてベースとなる具体的なコードがあれば回答が付きやすいかなと。

Comment: どれが相応しいか不明ですが、いくつか記事を見つけたので列挙しておきます。[記事１](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3884/Save-and-Load-TreeView-content), [記事２](https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/462900-save-load-treeview-sql-database), [記事３](https://forums.asp.net/t/1539515.aspx?TreeView+Load+Save+to+DB+checked+unchecked+Nodes), [記事４](https://forums.asp.net/t/1992962.aspx?How+to+save+treeview+data+into+database), [記事５](https://forums.asp.net/t/1637641.aspx?Save+data+from+treeview+checkbox), [記事６](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5868790/9014308)