# データベースのテーブルからTreeviewの作成する方法について

Tags: c#, asp.net

データベースのカラム構成が以下のように階層数が決まっている場合にこれらの項目のTreeviewを作成したいです。
どのようにデータのモデルをデータベースから検索してTreeview作成すれば良いでしょうか？

参考のソース等でもかまいませんのでご教示頂きたく宜しくお願いいたします。

以下のテーブルからSQLで検索した結果を階層構造に変換するやり方でもかまいません。

・テーブル構成
大項目,中項目,小項目
大1,中1,小1
大1,中1,小2
大2,中2,小3
大2,中2,小4

・作成したいTreeview
ルート
　　　大1
　　　　中1 
 　　　　　小1
　　　　　 小2
　　　大2
　　　　中2
　　　　　 小3
　　　　　 小4

自己レスです。単純に大項目、中項目、小項目の順にTreeNodeを親を指定して作成できました。
お騒がせしてもうしわけありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Treeview 選択値の保存方式を教えてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/50546/4236)でも質問の意図がいまいちよくわからなかったのですが、

SQL Server 2008以降にはツリー構造を表す[hierarchyidデータ型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/cc645577(v%3Dsql.100)#hierarchyid-%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E5%9E%8B)が導入されています。[階層データ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)で詳しい扱い方が説明されています。これを活用できないでしょうか？

Comment: 保存方式は、DBに保存致します。その際は、チェックした項目を上記のテーブル構成のように保存することを考えております。保存した大項目、中項目、小項目に該当する値がTreeViewにあればチェックする方式です。

Comment: hierarchyidデータ型というものは、扱ったことがないのですが、データベース検索した際に普通に文字列として取得できるものなのでしょうか？こちらのDB検索フレームワークがこの型に対応していないと考えられます。